# Errors in Training while running Mahout Naive Byes Algorithm on EMR

Tags: mahout

I tried to run naive byes algorithm using 1 master(small) and 1 slave(small) node on EMR. I successfully completed steps using seqdirectory, seq2sparse and split commands. But during training phase I got errors. I used following command to train the algorithm:

```
./elastic-mapreduce --jar s3n://<bucket name>/mahout/mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar \
    --main-class org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver \
    --logs \
    --arg trainnb \
    --arg -i --arg /<folder name>/mahout/review-train-vectors/ --arg -el\
    --arg -o --arg /<folder name>/mahout/model/ \
    --arg -li --arg /<folder name>/mahout/labelindex/ \
    --arg -ow \
    -j <job-name>
```

Here's the log of the job step:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:76)
at org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.training.WeightsMapper.setup(WeightsMapper.java:42)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:771)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:375)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

attempt_201302130846_0035_m_000000_0: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
attempt_201302130846_0035_m_000000_0: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop  /lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
attempt_201302130846_0035_m_000000_0: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/mapred/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201302130846_0035/jars/job.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
attempt_201302130846_0035_m_000000_0: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:76)
at org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.training.WeightsMapper.setup(WeightsMapper.java:42)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:771)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:375)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

attempt_201302130846_0035_m_000000_1: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
attempt_201302130846_0035_m_000000_1: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop  /lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
attempt_201302130846_0035_m_000000_1: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/mapred/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201302130846_0035/jars/job.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
attempt_201302130846_0035_m_000000_1: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:76)
at org.apache.mahout.classifier.naivebayes.training.WeightsMapper.setup(WeightsMapper.java:42)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:142)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:771)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:375)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1132)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)

attempt_201302130846_0035_m_000000_2: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
attempt_201302130846_0035_m_000000_2: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
attempt_201302130846_0035_m_000000_2: SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/mnt/var/lib/hadoop/mapred/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201302130846_0035/jars/job.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
attempt_201302130846_0035_m_000000_2: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

Anyone tried this thing before? Please help me to resolve this issue. I also have same issue when I run this algorithm using hadoop pseudo-distributed mode on my local system. This algorithm works only with MAHOUT_LOCAL=True environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

there  are problems with the command's arguments. It looks like you copy and paste command without adjusting it according to your environment:

```
  --jar s3n://<bucket name>/mahout/mahout-examples-0.7-job.jar
```

what is bucket name?

```
 --arg -i --arg /<folder name>/mahout/review-train-vectors/
```

`<folder name>` looks like a variable you should change according to your situation

```
-j <job-name>
```

the same kind of error. It seems you are not an experienced linux user, be aware character `\` at the end of each line should be skipped (most likely there are on the web page from where you took the command. The page is better readable (you are sure that it is one command - not many command on many lines):) )